# MySQL input from php json data (special characters)

Tags: php, mysql, json, special-characters

I was inserting some data on the fields of my website then i copy and pasted a string from another text editor(MS Word), then on my console log it recognizes the long single hyphen ( – ) which is the same as at PHP. But then when i execute the query the value from the database becomes different which is this:

```
`â€“`
```

This is the filtering that i do but as i said php recognizes it as a long hyphen ( – ) and that's the reason why they can't catch it. My question is why? Or any solution on the DB?

```
    $_raw_data = $_POST['edit_data'];
    $_raw_data = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\- \'"{},:;[]]/', '', json_encode($_raw_data));
    $_raw_data = str_replace("'", "''", $_raw_data);
    $_raw_data = json_decode($_raw_data, true);
```

Comment: What is your table charset and column collation?

Comment: col => latin1_swedish_ci. table => latin1_swedish_ci. Is there any settings where i can only include the common characters being used by the general people(users)? I dont really know this settings..

Comment: There are 3 areas you need them to be using the same char-set, Those are the database table , the connection with the database and the viewer (the program that draws the characters e.g the browser). Why not just using [unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and free your mind from errors like these ?

Comment: Yup, ise utf8mb4 as mentioned in the link which @Accountantم gave. It gives 4 bits which enough for most cases (special characters, japanese symbols, emotions and etc.) and use utf in connection